# Questions about BigDecimal multiply() method in Java

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I've been trying to avoid precision loss in case of using BigDecimal multiply() method in Java.

Please check an example code below.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
 
     double result = 0;
     NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.####################");
     formatter.setGroupingUsed(true);
 
     //10000000000
     //17911250000
     String strRt = formatter.format(10000000000.0);
     String strIrt = formatter.format(17911250000.0);
 
     System.out.println(strRt);
     System.out.println(strIrt);
 
     result = new BigDecimal(strRt).multiply(new BigDecimal(strIrt)).doubleValue();
 
    System.out.println(formatter.format(result));
 }

}
```

---

An expected result :

```
10000000000
17911250000
179112500000000000000
```

Result in console:

```
10000000000
17911250000
179112499999999980000
```

Is there any other way to get a precise result?

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is in calling `doubleValue()`, not in the result of `multiply()`. I would suggest you *start* by separating those aspects out - print the result of calling `multiply` and I suspect it'll be what you expect.

Comment: There is no precision loss in `BigDecimal` multiplication, but there is in conversion to `double`. Solution: don't.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `BigDecimal` is to avoid the lack of precision of `double` (and all other primitive number types). You however are using `double`s to read (but also create) the `BigDecimal`s thus reintroducing the lack of precision.

`DecimalFormat` directly supports `BigDecimal`, so there is no need to read the `doubleValue`. Also it's best to avoid using `double`s to create the input values.

```
 NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.####################");
 formatter.setGroupingUsed(true);

 String strRt = "10000000000";
 String strIrt = "17911250000";

 System.out.println(strRt);
 System.out.println(strIrt);

 BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(strRt).multiply(new BigDecimal(strIrt));

 System.out.println(formatter.format(result));
```

Comment: As a side note, `formatter.setGroupingUsed(true)` has no effect when no grouping size is set and specifying a ton of optional fractional digits has no effect on the whole numbers of the OP’s example either. So the result of this formatter is not different to `System.out.println(result);`